# Children of children Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, children

Say I had a div with two children divs that acted as columns for an undefined number of navigation buttons. 
Such as

```
<div id='controls'>
<div id='column1'><a id='button1' href=#></a></div>
<div id='column2'><a id='button2' href=#></a></div>
</div>
```

I currently have it like so

```
var column1 = document.getElementById('column1').children;
var column2 = document.getElementById('column2').children;
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');

button1.onclick = function() {
    column1.className = column1.className.replace(new RegExp('\b' + active + '\b'),'');
    column2.className = column2.className.replace(new RegExp('\b' + active + '\b'),'');
    this.className += ' active';
};
```

Since I'm doing the same thing to both, is there a way to combine it to be something along the lines of:

```
var controls = document.getElementById('controls').children.children;
```

or

```
var controls = document.getElementById('controls').children;
var controls = controls.children;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
var controls = document.querySelectorAll('#controls > div');
console.log(controls)
```

[Supports IE8+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility)

---

Here controls is an array, so you need to iterate them to change its properties

```
button1.onclick = function () {
    var controls = document.querySelectorAll('#controls > div');
    for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
        controls[i].className = controls[i].className.replace(new RegExp('\b' + active + '\b'), '');
    }
    this.className += ' active';
};
```

Comment: Ah, I get it. Should it be var controls = document.querySelectorAll('#controls > div a'); to select the anchor elements underneath the secondary div, or target the div itself?
Also, if each button had a common class .button (for example), could I use this to target them all (var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

Comment: @user3409230 yes.... `document.querySelectorAll('#controls > div a');`, if you don't any other anchor element within `#controls` then `document.querySelectorAll('#controls a');`